# I can ping a server but not connect via ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, ping

When I ping my server, it responds:

```
Pinging 192.168.2.222 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.2.222: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.222: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.222: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.222: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.2.222:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

When I used Xshell to connect the server, it responds but stoped at the following line:

```
Connecting to 192.168.2.222:22...
Connection established.
To escape to local shell, press 'Ctrl+Alt+]'.
```

A Rstudio server is running on the server, 192.168.2.222:8787 not responding too (always in the connecting status). Then I tried to ssh with debug, it also stoped at the last line:

```
>ssh -vvv 192.168.2.222
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.222 [192.168.2.222] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
```

Then I tried other way to diagnose the server with the following command line:

```
>nc -v -w 1 192.168.2.222 22
Connection to 192.168.2.222 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

Still I can't figure out what's going on! When I went to server room, server not reposne any thing with screen black. After I restarted computer manually, I can login the computer with ssh. But after some hours later, the problem happend again! I really don't know what's the problem, I am just a student, don't know much about linux server. Server running CentOS 6.5.

Comment: Need to show server's logs at time when this situation was. Also check RAM memory on the server.

Comment: usual guess: ssh not niced higher, other services high load, resulting in some tcp timeouts.

Comment: Check power saving if enabled (bios,centos). Check **abrt-cli status**, **abrt-cli list**, **journalctl** ... and post usefully results.

Comment: Is the time synchronized?
Is any log shown on the server side when the login fails?

Comment: You should check you `dmesg` output.

Comment: Thanks guys! I search `messages` and `dmesg` no error is presented. Since the last time I reboot the server, same thing never happed again. I really don't know what happed last time. But thanks for you all for the help.

Answer (score -1):

There can be problem with ssh protocol/package **try** to reinstall or upgrade open-ssh server package and regenerate keys

**How to regenerate new ssh server keys**

This is an unusual topic since most distribution create these keys for you during the installation of the OpenSSH server package. But it may be useful to be able generate new server keys from time to time, this happen to me when I duplicate Virtual Private Server which contains an installed ssh package.
OpenSSH require different keys depending if you use SSH1 and/or SSH2 protocol. All keys are generated by ssh-keygen, that one should be available on your system with the ssh package. The receipt is almost the same as for generating your own keys, except that you should use an empty passphrase. Default key lengths are also appropriate (2048 bits for rsa and 1024 bits for dsa)

SSH1 protocol
For SSH1 protocol, you need a rsa1 key generated has follow:
ssh-keygen -q -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key -N '' -t rsa1

SSH2 protocol
For SSH2 protocol, you need two keys, one RSA key and one DSA key generated has follow:

ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa

ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -N '' -t dsa

Since January 2011, OpenSSH also support ECDSA key, you may generate a new one using:
ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -N '' -t ecdsa -b 521

Comment: and this solved the issue of having a non-responsive ssh server how?

Comment: For me it solved the issue, reason i can say there might be some problem with the ssh protocol which was not able to validate the keys and solved by regenerating and using only ssh2 protocol